# Conservation of momentum for ball to triangular prism physics

Tags: conservation-laws

A ball of mass m1 is hitting a resting triangular prism of mass M with an unknown velocity of v1. After the hit the prism is moving forward with a velocity V and the ball up with the velocity V1a.

The surface of the prism making contact with the ball has a 45° angle regarding the lying surface. Assuming there is no friction between the prism and the lying surface, calculate V1 and V1a.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFAne.jpg

Applying the conservation of momentum in x-direction will deliever a value for V1. In y-direction the triangular prism will absorb the momentum, it will merely be pushed down.

The only idea that I can think of to calculate Via is applying the conservation of energy. Assuming the ball is hitting the prism along the horizontal line of its gravity center than is easily solvable.

What do you think of it?